# How do you view request bodies sent to a mock REST server in SoapUI?

Tags: rest, soapui

I've set up a mock REST server in SoapUI, and I am able to successfully get requests and send back responses.  However, I'd like to be able to view the content (body) of the request sent to my mock REST service.  How do I do that?  Left or right clicking on the "message log" entry associated with the request when running the mock server doesn't do anything.  I am using SoapUI 5.6.0.  The message log just shows there was a request and shows the endpoint hit, but doesn't show the actual request.

[image]

Comment: Double click on `/cdfauthtoken`.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal, that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to add an "OnRequest Script" to be able to get the request content.  The script reads:

```
log.info(mockRequest.getRequestContent())
```

Then you have to click on the "script.log" link/button at the bottom of the page.

[image]